# How to decide if a method should go in a data definition class (DDC) or the implementation class

Tags: java, algorithm, logic

I believe this is a fairly straightforward question, I just don't have the answer as I'm still relatively new to programming. I've been programming for over a year but I'm working on a project with another individual and we have had some disagreements over what methods should go where. I don't care about being right, but I would like to know what the best practice is in determining what to do.

**The general question:** Is there a rule of thumb on how to decide whether a method should go into a DDC class or should it go into the implementation class? Does it *really* matter if it works either way?

For instance, we have two classes: Student and Counselor. A student has a list of schedules (up to 4) and each schedule contains multiple courses. Both users can create schedules for a student. They can also view current schedule and view past schedules. Should the logic of these methods be in the implementation class and just call on certain methods (getSchedules) and manipulate it in certain ways to perform the functions we want or can the logic be in the DDC itself and from the implementation we just call the special methods from the implementation class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, to avoid duplicating code, the declarations should go in the DDC. An alternative would be to make a new class, User, which is extended by both Student and Counselor. However, you should never write the same method twice in two different classes.

The reason is that later, when you want to modify your code, it becomes hard to do if you have to modify it more than once. On larger projects, this can become a huge issue.

Comment: I did have an Abstract User class which both Student and Counselor extend. I didn't plan on duplicating the method by putting it anywhere twice. I do understand your reasoning which is what I do my best to follow. Disregarding duplicate code, I was more concerned with proper placement of certain methods within the program (DDC or Implementation) which I believe you answered.Thanks!